# AngularJS Directives why don't any class or style changes to children of the element apply?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-directive, ng-hide, jqlite

I'm currently using a directive for DOM changes for my application. I would like a button in element to hide on a state change.

HTML:

```
<div account layout="row" layout align="start center">
    <md-button id="accountIcon" class="md-icon-button">
        <md-icon aria-label="account" layout-align="center center">
            <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
        </md-icon>
    </md-button>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module("app")
.directive('account', ($document) => {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
            scope.$on('hideAccount', () => {
                angular.element($document[0].querySelector('#accountIcon')).addClass('ng-hide);   
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The event is received and function is fired.
The following also **don't** work.

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#accountIcon')).addClass('ng-hide'); 
angular.element(document.querySelector('#accountIcon')).css('display', 'none'); 
angular.element(document.querySelector('#accountIcon')).addClass('hide'); 
var accountIcon = element.children()[0];
accountIcon.addClass('ng-hide');
```

where:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Hopefully you get the gist. The following **did** work:

```
element.addClass('ng-hide')
```

Although obviously, I'm not looking to hide the entire element because there will be more buttons added soon. (not just an account icon).
Any help or documentation appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the console for errors?

`element.children()[0]` is a DOM Node, which doesn't have an `.addClass()` method. To use the `.addClass()` method, just do this:

```
element.children().eq(0).addClass('ng-hide');
```

But the question remains - why are you going out of your way to use DOM manipulations when you don't have to? Couldn't you just use the `ng-hide` directive within your directive? Accessing elements by ID and doing all these DOM manipulations seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your method worked a charm. 

The reason I'm using a directive is because I want to add more than one icon and the logic behind when the icons show is dictated by a mixture of different events and devices, too much for the ng-class attribute (if that's what you mean). 

I'm also lead to believe this type of DOM Manipulation is best off in a directive.

Comment: @Max The rule of thumb is that if you have DOM manipulation it should be in a directive, but it's even better to not use DOM manipulation at all. _"too much for the ng-class attribute (if that's what you mean)"_ No, I mean the [ng-hide directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide). I'm a bit doubtful when you say it's too complicated to do without DOM manipulations. Seems like DOM manipulations just make things _more_ complicated. If you're maintaining a simple model that dictates what should be shown and what should be hidden, then `ng-hide` or `ng-show` should be plenty.